# 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, symfony, windows-8.1

I am trying to install Symfony 2.7 as instructed by the manual.
When I open CMD (I am running it as an administrator in Windows 8.1) the default path is C:\Windows\System32. I have tried running the command specified in the documentation there (`c:\> php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony`), as well as in the root directory, both give me the same error.

I am using WAMP, the appache rewrite module and php_xls are activated.

I've also added the following to the PATH in the environment variables: `;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5;C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.0.45\bin`

After having added it, I rebooted the computer and still nothing worked. How can I install Symfony 2.7?

Comment: Have you tried putting the full path to the php executable? Something like `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5\php.exe -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony`. Verify that php.exe is in the folder C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5\

Comment: @Andrew I have tried `C:\>wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5\php.exe -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony` which gives me the following error: The system cannot find the patch specified and then I tried `C:\>cd\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5\php.exe -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony` which gives me the following error: The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.
I imagine that's because I have the `>` character after `C:\\`? How can I fix it?

Comment: What if you just run `C:\>wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5\php.exe -i`. This should just print the information about the current version of php and other info. If that doesn't work then I think you have the wrong path for your installation of php. Can you physically navigate to `wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5\php.exe`?

Comment: @Andrew the problem was indeed in the path, I have php5.5.12 not 5.2.5. I updated it, the file downloaded and I managed to move the file successfully: `c:\> move symfony c:\projects` However, I get the error The directory name is invalid when I execute the following command: `c:\>projects\ php symfony`

Comment: shouldn't it be `php projects\symfony`?

Comment: @Andrew not according to the symfony book, take a look: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html
Even if I try it I get the same error as in the beginning: `'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Comment: Oh, in the book they are already in the projects folder. So you should first do `cd projects` and then do `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php symfony`. Also I think you should update your PATH to the correct path for your version of php. Then you can just use the `php` command by itself.

Comment: You can also do `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php projects\symfony`

Comment: Sorry for my late reply @Andrew , I've been sick. I don't actually have a folder called php projects neither in the `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\` folder nor in `C:\`. What I have are two files, one named php and the other projects in `C:\`. If I go into the properties of both `php` and `projects`, in the type of file it just says: file

Comment: @Andrew If you want post it as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: Hey Lupy, I added the answer. Let me know if you are still having a problem. You just have to update your PATH and then do `php projects\symfony`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to your original problem:

You just have to make sure that the path to your php executable is correct when you add it to your PATH environment variable. This path is probably related to the version of PHP you have. You should be able to find this path by navigating inside your wamp installation and looking for the php folder and binary. In your case, this would be `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12`

However, for the new problem you have...

> However, I get the error The directory name is invalid when I execute
>   the following command: c:>projects\ php symfony

You just have to make sure that your PATH is updated with the correct path for your php, and then **do this from C:>**

```
php projects\symfony
```

Note that `php` is the executable and `projects\symfony` is the path to the symfony file.

Comment: The PATH is updated and now shows the correct version of PHP, I can also see the folder if I manually navigate to it. Now if I do `C:\>php projects\symfony` I get the following error: `could not open input file: projects\symfony` I also tried the following which resulted in the same error: `C:\>wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php projects\symfony`

Comment: I imagine that's because there is no projects folder in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12`?

Comment: @Lupy That would be true if you are running command prompt from that location. You have to start at C:\. To be very specific, you can do `php C:\projects\symfony`. This assumes that the php path is correctly added to PATH and there is a `symfony` file located at `C:\projects`. If these two conditions are true, then this should definitely work.

Comment: That seems to have been the problem. projects was a file, not a folder. I created the folder manually and inserted symfony, then it worked. Thanks a lot :)